# SharePoint library incoming mail setup not showing the full form settings

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2019, incoming-email

**Scenario**:

Two servers: SharePoint server 2019. Both the servers have the same version and build.

A collection of sites was transferred from one server to another (via `Backup-SPSite`).

On a restored site collection, I'm trying to set up incoming mail for one of the libraries.

But the settings form looks very truncated (most of the setting options are not available).

As a result, incoming mail works only if the letters differ in their subject.

**Example**: if you send two letters to the address of the library with the same subject "test123", then only one letter will appear in the library - the first one. The second will not come.

This issue has been identified for every library in this site collection.
Maybe someone faced a similar problem?

[image]

Comment: everything cleared up. This is not a problem. This is the result of having a custom mail receive event handler. It is this handler that changes the form of the settings.